# Reloaded modules ¿puede presentar un error?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en python 3.7 y todo me corre perfectamente pero al momento de ejecutarlo me aparece:

**Reloaded modules: funciones, etc**

y quiero saber si esto puede presentar algun problema o puedo dejarlo asi?

Gracias

Comment: Eso es un warning del IDE seguramente, estás importando de nuevo módulos ya importados, si lo haces en tu código simplememte importa solo al principio des script y no dentro de funciones y demás como se ve a veces. Pero me da que es cosa de ¿Spyder?, simplemente se debe a que los módulos fueron importados en la sesión de IPython en una ejecución anterior, no hay problema con ello. También puedes limpiar las variables de ejecuciones anteriores, a veces es recomendable si usas variables globales por ejemplo te puedes llevar sorpresas.

Comment: Ok gracias. Si es en spyder donde lo estoy realizando. Entonces no habria problemas al implementar un menu repetitivo?

Comment: Sin ver el código no sabría decir, ¿en el menú realizas imports repetidos? Generalmente los imports se deben hacer una sola vez al incio del script, al intéprete no le importa que importes de nuevo ni dónde lo hagas, pero generalmente no es buena práctica. Si importas una sola vez al incio es solo lo comentado sobre Spyder, puedes ignorarlo o resetear las variables de la consola IPython en cada ejecución. Si tienes dudas, agrega el código a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya entendi. gracias